# ScrollView is too slow

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm writing an application for social networking. So in the feeds page I have too many images, that makes scrolling extremely slow. I'm searching for a solution to the problem, but can't find anything really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can lazyLoad the images for the list view. [here](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/) is a complete example, it goes through everything you need to know about lazyloading

Comment: Actually problem is not in the loading but in the displaying too many images.

Answer (score 1):

Use lazy loading.Please download this [example](http://androidsnips.blogspot.in/2010/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-list-view-in.html).

Comment: just a personal thought of mine! it is all fine and good to download a full sample and just use that but you are not really learning about what you are using... it is much better to use tutorials that explain in detail what everything does so you can further understand and increase your programming knowledge, especially if you are going to be using something like lazyloading again